# Exposing a property in delphi to C++ from the VCL

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint is a property for TApplication, and according to the help, should be exposed in C++ Builder - Codegear 2007. It is not.

My difficulty is that I need to expose this to C++ or otherwise set it to true for my application.

So there are different avenues to accomplish this, and things I've tried and probably did wrong:

1. Exposed EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint in Forms.pas. However, I am having difficulty getting this change included into the application/VCL. I've tried everything I've read on recompiling the VCL. Nothing has worked.
2. Call some delphi code that *can* access the property from C++.
3. Something else?

I cannot upgrade to a newer version of Codegear, as this would break RTTI behavior the application relies on.

Suggestions? Solutions?

Comment: You're not supposed to use it. It's an internally-used property. See [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint)

Comment: @KenWhite: So the documentation says. But nothing in the RTL/VCL ever sets that property value, and it defaults to False, so unless users change its value to True manually, it is always False so it may as well not even exist in the first place. That effectively makes it a property meant for user-defined values, so the documentation is a bit misleading.

Comment: Its needed for ActiveX applications, especially coming into IE10 where the TabProcGrowth registry workaround won't work anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TApplication::EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint` was not introduced as a real C++-accessible property until C++Builder 2009. In C++Builder 2007, it was implemented as a property of a [Class Helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) instead:

```
TApplicationHelper = class helper for TApplication
private
  procedure SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(Flag: Boolean);
  function GetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint: Boolean;
  ...
public
  property EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint: Boolean read GetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint write SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint;
  ...
end;
```

[Class Helpers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) are a Delphi-specific feature that are not accessible in C++.  So you will have to use a workaround.  Create a separate .pas file that exposes C-style functions to access the       `EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint` property, and then add that .pas file to your C++ project:

AppHelperAccess.pas:

```
unit AppHelperAccess;

interface

function Application_GetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint: Boolean;
procedure Application_SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(Flag: Boolean);

implementation

uses
  Forms;

function Application_GetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Application.EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint;
end;

procedure Application_SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(Flag: Boolean);
begin
  Application.EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint := Flag;
end;

end.
```

When it gets compiled, a C++ .hpp header file will be generated that your C++ code can then use to call the functions.  For example

```
#include "AppHelperAccess.hpp"

void EnableEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint()
{
    Application_SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(true);
}

void DisableEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint()
{
    Application_SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(false);
}

void ToggleEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint()
{
    bool flag = Application_GetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint();
    Application_SetEnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint(!flag);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This worked perfectly, and seemed so obviously simple in retrospect.

Comment: Unfortunately, this flag does not appear to work for ActiveForms/ActiveX Controls in IE9/IE10 with TabProcGrowth set to >0. The flag gets set, however, hints are still not showing. Any ideas on this?